# istanbul-middleware showing "No Coverage information has been collected"

Tags: node.js, istanbul

I have followed the steps from https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul-middleware

But i get "No Coverage information has been collected".

Few things about this project:

- This project is using babel for compilation
- I use server.js to load the app
- I have added `im.hookLoader(__dirname);` at the beginning of the server.js
- I have added a route to /coverage with `im.createHandler()`

Any thought or comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added im.hookLoader(__dirname); before any require stmt (JS) or import stmt (TS).